# Event-Sourcing how to change business rules

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

My application use cqrs and event sourcing. It's already in production.
Now i must add a business rules. My business rules are in my aggregate root UserAggregate.

My commands :

```
public class CallUserForMarketingPlanCommand 
{
    public Guid UserId {get;set;}
    public DateTime CallDate {get;set;} 
    public Guid PlanId {get;set;}
}

public class AcceptMarketingPlanCommand
{
    public Guid UserId {get;set;}
    public Date AswerDate {get;set;}
    public Guid PlanId {get;set;}
}

... the same thing for RefuseMarketingPlanCommand
```

these commands are applied on my aggregate root which generate events stored in event store

Now if 50 days after the call, the user do not give answer, the user must be recalled by operator. To do this, i think generate event UserDoNotRepliedInDelayEvent and use it to project to a read model with recall informations.

My solution is to create a deferred command (from UserCalledForMarketingPlanEvent handler) CheckUserAnswerCommand which check the call date and generate UserDoNotRepliedInDelayEvent if necessary across the aggregate. Ok.

My problem is how to deffered this command on users already in my event store (before this change) ?

**EDIT :**

Without considering deferred message, how to change business rules (or a business rules parameter) affecting the state of an aggregate. Simple example :

Disable account if two payments are not permformed.

this rule come with the first deployement. Ok, now there are 1000 accounts disabled. The boss change the rule because the business is impacted, and want disable account if 5 payments are not performed.

How to enable account having less than 5 payments not performed ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Now if 50 days after the call, the user do not give answer, the user must be recalled by operator. To do this, i think generate event UserDoNotRepliedInDelayEvent and use it to project to a read model with recall informations.

If I undestood your question correctly, the main point here, is that the user "not replying" in time is not an action (command) of your domain, quite the contrary, it is the absence of an action. So in this scenario, I don't think you need an event at all.

You simply need a read model which will register all sent invitations and their statuses (whether they're replied, their reply dates and how long did they stand unanswered). Then, you can check this read model for unanswered invitations that exceed your deadline of 50 days (which should be simple enough at this point).

So, up to this point, no new events are generated in your "Invitations" event store. You're simply interpreting the store into a specific read model that will answer you a question you have (which invitations were not answered).

From this point, it depends on your architecture.

- You might want a recurring process to check this read model for invitations that exceed your deadline, having those specific invitations trigger a "InvitationExpiredEvent" or something to notify the interested parties (those who will resend them, for instance)
- Or you simply might want a more passive approach, not needing an extra event, simply reading this Read Model when appropriate (on the GUI, maybe) and listing the expired invitations.

This will then fix itself... since you can generate the read model retroactively (finding users from any given point in the that never answered their invitations) and put them through the re-invitation pipeline.

> Without considering deferred message, how to change business rules (or a business rules parameter) affecting the state of an aggregate. Simple example :
>
> Disable account if two payments are not permformed.
>
> this rule come with the first deployement. Ok, now there are 1000 accounts disabled. The boss change the rule because the business is impacted, and want disable account if 5 payments are not performed.
>
> How to enable account having less than 5 payments not performed ?

This part of your question is more confusing. From what I understood, you once had a rule that stated "Accounts with two or more expired payments should be inactivated" and you want to change this rule to "Accounts with five or more expired payments should be inactivated". If that's the case, you have to deal with this on multiple levels...

- First, you must first implement the new rule on your command model, the same way it always have been but with the updated parameter.
- Second, you **cannot** retroactively reactivated accounts with 2,3,4 expired payments by ignoring their "deactivation events". From your event store point of view, this happened and you must abide by the rules that an **event store is a "push only" storage**. So, you must use compensating events to reactivate them after the rule change.

So, if you took care of the first topic (and your domain is up and running with the new rule) and since you can't take a shortcut because of the second topic, one of your easier options is to simply develop a one-shot operation that will find accounts with 2,3,4 expired payments that are currently disabled and append to their event stores a reactivation event. At this point you will have to regenerate any affected read models if your architecture doesn't do this automatically.

That way, the next time commands are executed against these accounts, their event stores will reflect the fact that they have been reactivated and thus are currently active.

From an event store point of view... each of these accounts will have something like this on their event streams:

... > Payment Expired > Account Disabled > (maybe other stuff happened) > Account Re-Enabled

So your event store will be a pretty accurate representation of your business scenario... once you chose to disable accounts with only 2 expired payments, so a certain account was disabled by that... later you changed your mind, and even without paying their debts, these accounts were re-enabled.

EDIT:

> In fact, i think the problem can be summarized by "how to integrate retroactive rules in event sourced system"

If that's the case, than the answer will be more focused on the lines of "there shouldn't be retroactive actions in an event-sourced domain".

As I said in my original answer, an event stream should be a "push-only" storage and that's mainly because only the exact order of events, as they happened, can guarantee the integrity of your rules as they were when those events happened. In that sense, an event storage is less flexible than a traditional one as it will be way more sensitive to external interference and that will sometimes be a pain (were used to meddling with the data sources directly to fix stuff).

However, we should really try to keep the rule and acknowledge that whatever happened, happened and can't be changed. What you can do, is add, to the end of event stream "compensation events" that is, new events that will register a change of state at a given time to reflect your rules-changing. And then you will need a one-shot process to go through your entities and decide which of them are eligible for such a compensating event.

Now, of course, rules are meant to be broken when needed and with enough consideration, you can go wild into the event store. Just know the risks. If you choose to go "full time machine mode" into the event store, the main risks you will face (and should guard against) are:

- Entities going into invalid states in their lifetime. It doesn't matter the entity "ends" the event stream in a valid state. You must validate it never enters an invalid state as that is a prerequisite of event streams. So, for each entity affected by your editing, you will need to evaluate its validity step by step through the new event stream.
- Mismatches between source code and event stream. This is a little trickier. But one of the maneuvers you can pull with an event sourced system is rollback your source code repository to a given date and "discard" events from that date forward. That way, you can re-execute actions as they would have happened in the past. If you edit past events though, you might face situations where the recorded events don't match what would have happened in the past based on source code. That might be critical and extremely misleading in the future. You should monitor that.
- If your architecture integrates different contexts/domains/microservices, that might also need further evaluation. Say context-A issued a cross-boundary message to context-B because of a given state of an entity. Moving forward, you change the entity state by meddling with the event stream. Now there's a chance these contexts might be left inconsistent between them as context-B believes that entity had a state it no longer has. This might be very relevant in your scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your repsonse. In fact, i think the problem can be summarized by "how to integrate retroactive rules in event sourced system"...

Answer (score 0):

you could also use a Saga that keeps track of the process and than create a command like "recallneeded" when the time is up. it also keeps track of events that tells the Saga to complete if there was a call within the 50 days. (Keep in mind that a Saga is part of your Domain logic and acts as an AR if doing DDD)